# Weird space/margin between Polymer elements

Tags: css, polymer

I'm starting out with Polymer and despite the fact I really see its "power", I've been struggling with a weird issue. I have a "ghost space" (looks like a margin) between each and every Polymer elements in my project. And always when I check them in Chrome Dev Tools, their computed margins and paddings are always zeroed (as expected). But, even though, they are rendered with a white space between them. I have also checked all inner elements (there aren't many, since I have just started out and I'm still trying it), all of them have zero padding and margins and I still have this ghost margin between elements. The same strange, unidentifiable, not defined margin is set between my uppermost element and the document body tag.

What is happening? What am I missing?

By the way, I'm using Polymer CLI to serve my dev environment. Maybe this could be a bug on polymer serve command...

Here is the code:

***app/index.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="import" href="/src/myapp-app/myapp-app.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <myapp-app></myapp-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

***app/src/myapp-app/myapp-app.html***

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="myapp-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="myapp-content/myapp-content.html">
<link rel="import" href="myapp-footer.html">

<dom-module id="myapp-app">
  <template>
    <style type="text/css">
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-height: 100vh; }

    </style>

    <myapp-header></myapp-header>
    <myapp-content></myapp-content>
    <myapp-footer></myapp-footer>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'myapp-app'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

***app/src/myapp-app/myapp-header.html***

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="myapp-header">
  <template>
    <style type="text/css">
    :host {
      display: block; }

    </style>

    <h1>A header</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'myapp-header',
      properties: {},
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

***app/src/myapp-app/myapp-content/myapp-content.html***

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="myapp-content">
  <template>
    <style type="text/css">
    :host {
      display: block; }

    </style>

    <h1>Content</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'myapp-content',
      properties: {},
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

***app/src/myapp-app/myapp-footer.html***

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="myapp-footer">
  <template>
    <style type="text/css">
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 10vh;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0; }

    </style>

    <h1>A footer</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'myapp-footer',
      properties: {},
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Do you set `margin` and `padding` to zero for `html` and/or `body`? Could you provide a screenshot, or even better - a working example (in JSBin or JSFiddle etc.).

Comment: Hello @alesc! I have zeroed `margin` and `padding` for the `html` and `body` tags as well. These settings are defined in the `main.css` that is being loaded at the `index.html` page. See `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/main.css">`. When I get home I'll post the `main.css` as well as a print screen of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as I imagined my mistake was a really "nooby" one. My element tags had an "ghost" space because of the margin set by the h1 tags inside of them. So, in fact, there were no ghosts at all, just my "newbines". =x